# wp7 - App.ViewModel collection Selection

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a collection:

```
App.ViewModel.historyItemCollection
```

That has 4 properties:

- id
- name
- meterValue
- meterDate

I would like to bind to my listbox by id.  So if I select house #2 (in the collection) I only want to show the history information for house 2.

I tried a couple of different selects/where statements when trying to bind it to my form:

```
    lbHistory.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.historyItemCollection.Where(history => history.id= houseIndex);
```

If there are any links that say how to do this, please just point me there?  Part of my problem I couldn't figure out what this was called so my searches were fruitless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, so forgive me if it doesn't work.

```
lbHistory.ItemsSource = from item in App.ViewModel.historyItemCollection
                        where item.id == houseIndex
                        select item;
```

If there can be more than one match, and you only want to show the first, use:

```
lbHistory.ItemsSource = ( from item in App.ViewModel.historyItemCollection
                          where item.id == houseIndex
                          select item ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was the answer I needed.  What would you call this process (for future reference)?

Comment: @JeffV: The code is using LINQ to query a collection; here is a getting started guide - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx